# div que se mueve junto con el scroll en una misma posición con jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Cree una aplicación de chat ahora tengo que implementarla en el sitio web, el diseño es similar al de Facebook pero quiero que cuando el usuario haga scroll el chat se mantenga estático, es decir que al bajar con el scroll se mantenga en esa misma posición al estilo Facebook, en realidad cuando se hace scroll esta bajando pero se mantiene en la misma posición esto es lo que busco, lo que logro actualmente es que baje al pie de pagina al hacer scroll, pero lo que busco es que se mantenga en esa misma posición cuando el usuario haga scroll similar en resumen al chat de Facebook.

```js
var static_chat = jQuery("#masefic_chat_out");
var position_chat = static_chat.offset().top;
var page_position = jQuery(document).scrollTop();       
jQuery(document).scroll(function(event){
   var position_actually = jQuery(document).scrollTop();
   if(position_actually>position_chat){
   static_chat.animate({
    top: "+"+jQuery("#move_to").offset().top
   },100);
   }else if(page_position<position_actually||position_actualy===position_chat){
   alert("test"); // TEST para saber cuando vuelve a la posición original
   }
   
});
```

Comment: Qué tal si mejor utilizas `position:fixed`?

Comment: eso mismo venía a decir

Comment: y en donde lo implementaria?

Comment: Lo agregas en el CSS al elemento que quieres mantener fijo en la pantalla, en este caso el contenedor del chat.

Comment: jajajajajaj! gracias señores, -.- no puedo creer que con un solo atributo css me ahorro todo ese código, lo que pasa es que antes lo tenia en absoluto, y era mas laborioso, gracias!

Comment: Creo que @Jemonge debiera añadir sus comentarios como respuesta para que el OP pudiera marcarla como solucionada

Comment: @amenadiel respuesta agregada. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una mejor opción es utilizar el atributo `position:fixed;`, así te ahorras el trabajo de programarlo en Javascript. De esta manera sólo tendrías que agregar este atributo en el CSS al elemento que quieres mantener fijo en la pantalla, en este caso el contenedor del chat.

El CSS debería contener algo así:

```
#contenedorChat
{
    position: fixed;
}
```